# Rails - problem installing Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, spree

I'm having a problem installing Spree in a Rails app.

when I run gem 'spree'
(as per the instructions on http://spreecommerce.com/documentation/getting_started.html)

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command spree
```

I have the following Spree gems installed:

```
gem list spree

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

spree (0.30.1)
spree_api (0.30.1)
spree_auth (0.30.1)
spree_core (0.30.1)
spree_dash (0.30.1)
spree_promo (0.30.1)
spree_sample (0.30.1)
```

when I installed the Spree gem I used:

```
sudo gem install spree
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: Using Windows 7 I successfully installed gem install spree. Which operating system you are using am using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [instructions](https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/tutorials/getting_started_tutorial.html#adding-spree-to-your-rails-application) actually say to add `gem 'spree'` to your `Gemfile` (and not execute it as a command):

> Add Spree gems to your Gemfile:
>
> ```
> gem 'spree', '~> 4.1'
> gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 4.2'
> gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.9'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Spree gem install instructions: https://gist.github.com/kany/6334724