# Getting started with Spree Installation Trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, rubygems, shopping-cart, spree

So...

It looks like there are two ways to get started with Spree as far as implementing it into your Rails application, neither of which work...

**Method A**

```
$ spree mystore
```

*Result*

```
spree: command not found
```

**Method B**

```
$ rails cart
$ cd cart
$ rails g spree:site
```

*Result*

I get spit out the man page for the "rails" command as if it has no idea what I'm talking about.

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -J, [--skip-prototype]      # Skip Prototype files
  -T, [--skip-test-unit]      # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--dev]                 # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your            Rails checkout
  -G, [--skip-git]            # Skip Git ignores and keeps
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]   # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem      path or URL)
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]     # Path to an application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
```

and so on...

---

Here's what I've done:

```
$ sudo gem install spree #and all of its dependencies
```

My Gemfile:

```
source :rubygems
# Generic gem dependencies first
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'

# Followed by spree itself first, all spree-specific extensions second
gem 'spree'
gem 'spree_active_shipping', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_active_shipping.git'
gem 'spree_product_assembly', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree-product-assembly.git'
gem 'spree_static_content', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_static_content.git'
# EOF
```

And ran

```
$ bundle install
```

So what am I missing, my wonderful S.O. community?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this figured out.

- HAS to be Rails 3. I became a big boy yesterday and upgraded.
- Ran into a crapton of problems after this so make sure spree gemversion matches in gemfile and with your gem list (mine was 0.50.2) this doesn't really happen by default.
- This

  ```
  gem 'spree_static_content', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree-static-content.git'
  ```

has to become

```
gem 'spree_static_content', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_static_content.git'
```

in your gemfile, the documentation is wrong.

- You have to edit line #6 in /home/user/.bundler/ruby/1.8/spree_active_shipping-cb4f80aeb9c9/lib/tasks/active_shipping_extension_tasks.rake to reflect "RAILS_ROOT" instead of "something_shippy_thingy.root"
- You have to run

  ```
  rails g spree_product_assembly:install
  rails g spree_static_content:install
  rake db:migrate
  ```

So yeah, a lot of digging and most of this NOT in the documentation. Hopefully someone else finds this and its useful

Answer (score 1):

As they described on their [Github](https://github.com/spree/spree), you have to a create a new rails application and add gem 'spree' to gemfile and then do bundle install.

Comment: I have gem 'spree' in my gemfile and I made a new Rails application before running $ rails g spree:site. I'll update my post to be clear

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362115/rails-problem-installing-spree  check this

Comment: Yeah that's what I followed in my "Method b"

Comment: Can you see spree on your gem list?

Comment: Yep :\ this is getting sad, isn't it?